# Complete HTML ID

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, getelementbyid

it is possible to reduce the ID?

```
$ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_27855e01_08c1_498d_b130_0b761c472fbd_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").value = "Test Text"
```

like (Not working!)

```
$ie.Document.getElementById("*ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").value = "Test Text"
```

Comment: hmmm , where did that id come from ? , the function that created that HTML object with that ID can be modified to give smaller IDs

Comment: sorry Ronan, the ID is from a SharePoint Field and not modifiable :-(

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery:

```
$('[id$=ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField]').val("Test Text");
```

Of course, the performance will suffer, but unless this happens a lot on a large page, it won't be noticeable.